# UITableView cell as a function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This might sound like a dumb question but I am not sure where to find this or even where to start. I have a static cell that I need to come us as an Action Sheet but when I try and CLT + Drag to the .swift file I only get the outlet or outlet collection option and In order for it to be an AlertAction I need it to be a function, can anybody help me out?

Comment: You are going to have to give us some more details if you want help with your problem. Can you be more specific? To add an AlertAction is pretty simple. Please find the Apple Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

Answer (score 1):

Implement method `optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` of `UITableViewDelegate`.